# decimal round off: why?

Tags: c#, .net

```
string a = "9.42";
string b = "1610.25";

decimal aa = decimal.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal bb = decimal.Parse(b, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

decimal res = decimal.Multiply(aa, bb);
string res2 = res.ToString("#0.00", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE"));
```

Result

```
//res = 15168.555
//res2 = "15168,56"
```

I want output res2=15168,55. How to achive it?

Comment: Why do you want 15168,55? Because you want to always round down? or because you want to always have an odd last digit? or for some other reason?

Comment: my guess is 9.42 is may a tax percentage? and the OP is having probs getting the sum of all values * tax = sum of (individual values * tax)

Comment: @erikkallen: I always want two digits after decimal but no round...

Comment: @RRDD You need to round by definition if you want less digits. So I guess what you want is to round down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default rounding method is to round a midpoint value to the closest even decimal, e.g. `1.555` is rounded to `1.56` but `1.585` is rounded to `1.58`.

You can use the `Math.Floor` method to round down, but it doesn't have an overload where you can specify the number of decimal places, so you need to multiply and divide:

```
res = Math.Floor(res * 100m) / 100m;
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string res2 = (Math.Floor(res * 100) / 100).ToString();
```

Comment: this produces the same result as OP's.

Comment: This is how rounding works and u can't turn it off, so u need to bypass it.